# Display of modulus remainder

Tags: assembly, nasm, dos, x86-16, integer-division

Good day,New to nasm here.
This is run in win32(org 0x100).
Want to display the modulus remainder next to mess4 "the remainder is:" after the input(1-9) was given and if 7 or 8 or 9 then give the remainder from modulus.
Another problem is that still getting use to syntax so my "cmp" from input to 7(also 8 and 9 as 7 can divide into 8,9 and has remainder 1,2) catches on input values 1 and 2 as this is the same as remainder after dividing 8 and 9 with 7 has remainder 1 and 2 so gives a false reading.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Tried changing and moving in registrars to no avail.

Update: i'm able to display remainder on screen, only issue is to get appropriate call when dividing 7 so that it only calls 'isdiv' when value 7,8,9 is given.

```
bits 16
org 0x100 ; start offset at memory position 100
jmp main ; jump to main program
;
; Data definitions
;
mess1: db 'Input any number (1 - 9)', 0dh,0ah,'$'
mess2: db 'The number is divisible by 7',0dh,0ah,'$'
mess3: db 'The number is not a divisible by 7',0dh,0ah,'$'
mess4: db 'The remainder is: ',0ah, 0dh,'$'                     ;Not sure
errmess: db '**',0dh,0ah,'$'
crlf: db 0dh,0ah, '$'
;
; Display a string on the screen
; DX contains the address of the string
;
display:
    mov ah,09 
    int 21h 
    ret
;
;Display the remainder
remainder:

    mov dx,mess4
    call display
    ret
; Set the cursor position
;
cursor:
    mov ah,02
    mov bh,0 ; screen number mov
    mov dh,05h ; row
    mov dl,0 ; column
    int 10h
    ret
;
; Display a user prompt
;
prompt:
    mov dx,mess1
    call display
    ret
;
; Read one character from the keyboard
;
input:
    mov ah,01
    int 21h
    ret
;
; Clear screen and change screen colour
;
screen:
    mov ah,06 ; scroll up screen
    mov al,0 ; lines to scroll where 0 clear entire screen
    mov cx,0 ; starting row:column
    mov dl,80 ; ending row;column
    mov dh,80
    mov bh,00011110b ; colour: yellow on blue
    int 10h
    ret
;
; Carriage returnm and line feed
;
newline:
    mov dx,crlf
    call display
    ret
;
; Main program
;
main:
    call screen
    call cursor

next:
    call prompt
    call input
    cmp al,'1' ; character < 1?
    jl error ; yes, error message
    cmp al,'9' ; character > 9?
    jg error ; yes, error message   
    sub al,30h ; convert from ASCII to numeric
    xor ah,ah ; clear AH
    mov bl,7    
    idiv bl ; divide by 7
    mov ch,ah
    ;cmp ah,0  ; remainder = n0?
    je isdiv ; yes: divisible by 7
    call newline
    mov dx,mess3 ; not divisible by 7
    call display
    jmp fin



isdiv:
    call newline
    mov dx,mess2
    call display ; divisible by 7
    call remainder
    add ch,30h
    mov dl,ch
    mov ah,2h
    int 21h

fin:
    ;
    int 20h ; terminate program
    ; Display error message. Number out of range
    ;

error:
    mov dx,errmess
    call display
    jmp next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added mov cl,al ;to copy initial input for later use at cmp cl,7 and use jge isdiv to display remainder.
this solved my issue.

Comment: Jumping to **_isdiv_** using `cmp cl,7` `jge isdiv` will show a message that need not be true!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> idiv bl ; divide by 7
> mov ch,ah
> ;cmp ah,0  ; remainder = n0?
> je isdiv ; yes: divisible by 7
> ```

The `idiv` instruction does **not define any flags**. Without explicitly comparing `AH` for zero, the conditional jump will execute irratically.

When the code finds that the inputted number is not divisible by 7, it should not jump to the end (`jmp fin`), but rather to a point where you can decide whether displaying the remainder is requested.
You only want to see the remainder for inputs "7", "8", and "9".
You can easily filter these out because the quotient will be **1** as opposed to **0** for the smaller inputs "1" through "6"!

```
    sub  al, 30h   ; convert from ASCII to numeric
    cbw
    mov  bl, 7    
    div  bl
    mov  cx, ax    ; SAVE for parts 1 and 2 of the task
    call newline
    test ch, ch    ; Remainder saved earlier
    jz   isdiv     ; Divisible by 7
    mov  dx, mess3 ; Not divisible by 7
    call display
    jmp  part2
isdiv:
    mov  dx, mess2
    call display

part2:
    cmp  cl, 1     ; Quotient saved earlier
    jne  fin       ; Input was "1", "2", ... , "6"
    mov  dx, mess4
    call display
    mov  dl, ch    ; Remainder saved earlier
    add  dl, 30h
    mov  ah, 02h
    int  21h
    call newline

fin:
    int  20h
```

> ```
> mess4: db 'The remainder is: ',0ah, 0dh,'$'                     ;Not sure
> ```

The colon **:** suggests that you want the remainder to show **behind** the text. Best drop the carriage return and linefeed then. You can call for a separate *newline* afterwards.

```
mess4: db 'The remainder is: $'
```

---

> ```
> screen:
> mov ah,06 ; scroll up screen
> mov al,0 ; lines to scroll where 0 clear entire screen
> mov cx,0 ; starting row:column
> mov dl,80 ; ending row;column
> mov dh,80
> mov bh,00011110b ; colour: yellow on blue
> int 10h
> ret
> ```

The 80x25 text screen ends with column `DL=79` and row `DH=24`.